# iOS: Draw shadow within UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, core-graphics

I found some great code that is a subclass of `UIView` which draws that view with a shadow.  Then I can use that view anywhere I want to place the shadow:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
    CGFloat coloredBoxMargin = 40;
    CGFloat coloredBoxHeight = self.frame.size.height;
    _coloredBoxRect = CGRectMake(coloredBoxMargin, 0, 40, coloredBoxHeight);
}

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGColorRef lightColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:0.8].CGColor;
    CGColorRef shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.2 blue:0.2 alpha:0.4].CGColor;   

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Draw shadow
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightColor);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(-13, 0), 10, shadowColor);

    CGContextFillRect(context, _coloredBoxRect);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Created using the following:

```
UIViewWithShadowRight* verticalLineView2 = [[[UIViewWithShadowRight alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 40 , self.view.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
[verticalLineView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[verticalLineView2 setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[verticalLineView2 setClipsToBounds:NO];
[self.view addSubview:verticalLineView2];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:verticalLineView2];
```

**Problem is, the shadow is drawn from right to left, how can I reverse this and draw it left to right?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `13` positive instead of negative. That is the x-offset of the drawn shadow, with negative values being to the left of the original drawing, and positive values being to the right.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to help.  It makes the shadow disappear.

Comment: Show your code. This is the actual answer you're looking for so if you're seeing different results, it may be due to some other setting you've changed on the graphics context.

Comment: Jonathan, I updated my post with the code used to create the view.

Comment: Drawing is still clipped to the view's bounds, so the shadow won't draw outside of it. Make the view wider than its content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(-13, 0), 10, shadowColor);
Replace the current x value (-13) to the value on the right.